# как правильно указать диапазон генерации [65,132]?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

как правильно указать диапазон генерации  [65,132]?
для генерации пользоваться функцией rand()

Comment: а почему бы не пользоваться библиотекой `random` а не функцией `rand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
x = rand() % (132-64) + 65;
```